# Find the last row that meets a query condition with Sails.js

Tags: sails.js, waterline

What would be the best solution to find only one record with a Waterline - Sails query that search the last inserted price for the room2 in the given date?

```
ID  PRICE   START       STOP        ROOM    createdAt           updatedAt
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
85  750.00  2016-01-01  2017-12-31  room1   2016-02-25 10:09:47 2016-02-25 10:09:47
86  590.00  2016-01-01  2017-12-31  room2   2016-02-25 10:09:55 2016-02-25 10:09:55
90  410.00  2016-02-25  2016-02-27  room2   2016-02-25 16:46:08 2016-02-25 16:46:08
91  310.00  2016-01-26  2016-04-28  room2   2016-02-26 09:35:26 2016-02-26 09:35:26
```

I get wrong results doing these:

```
var where = {"start":{"<=":"2016-02-25T23:00:00.000Z"},"end":{">=":"2016-02-25T23:00:00.000Z"},"room":"room2"}

PriceHistory.find(where).max('createdAt').exec(function(err, prices){
        res.json(prices);
});
```

Comment: You have both dates to be same right now `{"<=":"2016-02-25T23:00:00.000Z"},"end":{">=":"2016-02-25T23:00:00.000Z"}`

Comment: @yury-tarabanko I've correctly re-edited the question I'm looking for a price in a given date (2016-02-25)

Answer (score 7):

How about using descending sort by createdAt and limiting to one record?

```
PriceHistory.find(where)
    .sort('createdAt DESC')
    .limit(1)
    .exec(function(err, prices){
        res.json(prices);   // should return one record (last one)
    });
```